# Angular - Combine params and queryParams observables

Tags: angular, angular-observable

How can I combine these to observables into one? They have the same functionality.

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
    // functionality
});

this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
    // same functionality   
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to do that:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

// ...

class MyComponent {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const params = this.route.params;
    const queryParams = this.route.queryParams;

    combineLatest(params, queryParams, (params, qparams) => ({ params, qparams }))
      .subscribe(allParams => console.log(allParams.params, allParams.qparams));
  }

}
```

params and qparams will be objects with the property name as the param name and the value as the value. So for a route:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([{
  path: 'test1/:id',
  component: Test1Component
}])
```

with params

```
http://localhost:4200/test1/paramvalue?qparam=qpvalue
```

allParams will be

```
{ 
  params: { 
     id: "paramvalue" 
    },
  qparams: { 
     qparam: "qpvalue" 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: allParams ahve inside 2 objects "params" and "qparams". Params is ok but qparams has params: "[object Object]" and qparams: "[object Object]" and all the other actual params

Comment: @Michalis I added some more detail to the answer both the params properties will be objects.

Comment: did you see the screenshot?

Comment: I don't get the same results. I'm on Angular 4.3.1.

Comment: I'm  using the default router configuration. I'm not sure whether anything on that side could make the ActivatedRoute different.

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
Need add import statment to work with Observable object.

Comment: @maheshkajale That will import everything. To just import Observable  if you are using < version 6 use `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Comment: It works fine except one case that change url from http://localhost:4200/test1/paramvalue?qparam=qpvalue to http://localhost:4200/test1/otherParamValue. At that time combineLatest run twice one for query param and other for path param. 
How can we solve this problem?